# Llamar función de una clase PHP

Tags: php

tengo un problema con mi código, y es que el código no llama a la función verificar y registrar de la clase usuarios. Este es el código:

```
if(strpos($datos[1], " ") == false){
                //Verificar si el usuario existe en la BD
                if(empty(usuarios::verificar($datos[1]))){
                    //Si no existe lo registramos
                    usuarios::registrar($datos);
                }else{
                    $error = "Usuario existente";
                }
            }else{
                $error = "Usuario con espacios";
            }
```

Y me muestra el siguiente error: 
Strict standards: Non-static method usuarios::verificar() should not be called statically in C:\wamp\www\Red_Social\registro.php on line 27

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\wamp\www\Red_Social\clases\clases.php on line 22.

Y esta es la clase usuarios:

```
class usuarios{
        //Registrar dato a la BD
        function registrar($datos){
            $con = conexion("root", "root");//Hago la conexion
            //Hago la consulta
            $consulta = $con->prepare("insert into usuarios(CodUsa, nombre, usuario, pass, pais, profesion, edad) values(null, :nombre, :usuario, :pass, :pais, :profesion, :edad)");
            //Ejecuto la consulta
            $consulta->execute(array(
                                ':nombre'=>$datos[0],
                                ':usuario'=>$datos[1],
                                ':pass'=>$datos[2],
                                ':pais'=>$datos[3],
                                ':profesion'=>$datos[4],
                                ':edad'=>$datos[5]
            ));
        }//end function

        //Verificar si existe
        function verificar($usuario){
            $con = conexion("root", "root");
            $consulta = $con->prepare("select * from usuarios where usuario = :usuario");
            $consulta->execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));
            $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
            return $resultado;
        }//end function
    }
```

Y aquí esta el archivo funciones.php, donde están todas las funciones:

```
function conexion($usuario, $contra){
        try{
            //Hago conexion con PDO
            $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=reed_social', $usuario, $contra);
            return $con;
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            return $e->getMessage();//Mensaje de error
        }
    }//end function

    function datos_vacios($datos){
        $vacio = false;
        $tam = count($datos);
        for($i=0; $i<$tam; $i++){
            //Si algún dato está vacío
            if(empty($datos[$i])){
                $vacio = true;
                break;
            }//end if
        }//end for
        return $vacio;
    }//end function

    function limpiar($datos){
        $tam = count($datos);
        for($i=0; $i<$tam; $i++){
            if($i != 2){
                //Limpiar datos de espacios, etc.
                $datos[$i] = htmlspecialchars($datos[$i]);
                $datos[$i] = trim($datos[$i]);
                $datos[$i] = stripcslashes($datos[$i]);
            }//end if
        }//end for
        return $datos;
    }//end function
```

Gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: pon el código de las demás clases que utilices, para ayudarte mejor.Un saludo

Comment: @montes18295 Ya está añadida la clase a la pregunta, gracias por decirlo

Comment: falta clases.php para el segundo error. Un saludo.

Comment: @montes18295 El archivo clases.php es la clase que he mostrado.

Comment: Donde está la función conexión?

Comment: @montes18295 Perdón, ya he añadido a la pregunta las funciones. No doy una jaja

Comment: Edite la respuesta, echa un vistazo

Comment: Creo que hay un problema de *organización de código*. Digo esto porque tú creas la conexión en un archivo llamado `funciones.php`. Eso significa que donde quiera que necesites usar la conexión deberás hacer un `include` o un `require` **de ese archivo completo**. Generalmente, lo que se hace es crear una `clase` en la cual creas la conexión, con un método que te devuelve el objeto conexión. Entonces, cuando necesitas la conexión creas una instancia de esa clase y obtienes la conexión. No me parece una buena idea poner la conexión en un archivo de funciones.

Comment: El error que te da con respecto al `prepare` es por eso, porque aquí `$con = conexion("root", "root");` no obtienes la conexión realmente. Además, fíjate que ese archivo maneja datos muy sensibles, como podrían ser el nombre de usuario  y la contraseña de conexión a la base de datos... ese tipo de información no conviene que vaya rodando de un lado para otro, siendo pasada como parámetros de funciones. Toda esa información debería estar en una clase dedicada exclusivamente a gestionar las conexiones, de ese modo, tú obtienes la conexión así: `$con=new Conexion();`  o a través de un `getter`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Entonces me aconsejarías crear una clase solo para crear la conexión y después crear un objeto de conexión?

Comment: O sea, siempre conviene tener una clase dedicada exclusivamente a la conexión por varios motivos. Supongamos que tú tienes por todas partes llamadas como esta: `$con = conexion("root", "root");`, pero resulta que se decide cambiar el nombre de usuario o la contraseña... vas a tener que empezar a buscar **por todo tu código** las llamadas que has hecho de esa manera para actualizar las credenciales. Teniendo la clase de conexión sólo cambiarías las credenciales en la clase y listo. Con una clase conexión se harían en el futuro funciones más avanzadas, como operaciones tipo `CRUD`, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Debe tener los métodos estáticos para referenciarlos como tal:

```
class usuarios{
        //Registrar dato a la BD
        public static function registrar($datos){
            $con = conexion("root", "root");//Hago la conexion
            //Hago la consulta
            $consulta = $con->prepare("insert into usuarios(CodUsa, nombre, usuario, pass, pais, profesion, edad) values(null, :nombre, :usuario, :pass, :pais, :profesion, :edad)");
            //Ejecuto la consulta
            $consulta->execute(array(
                                ':nombre'=>$datos[0],
                                ':usuario'=>$datos[1],
                                ':pass'=>$datos[2],
                                ':pais'=>$datos[3],
                                ':profesion'=>$datos[4],
                                ':edad'=>$datos[5]
            ));
        }//end function

        //Verificar si existe
        public static function verificar($usuario){
            $con = conexion("root", "root");
            $consulta = $con->prepare("select * from usuarios where usuario = :usuario");
            $consulta->execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));
            $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
            return $resultado;
        }//end function
    }
```

En cuanto al segundo error, creo que en la función te esta entrando en el catch, y te devuelve un String con el mensaje de error, lo que lanza el:

> fatal error call to a member function prepare() on string

Prueba a incluir el archivo funciones en el archivo de las clase:

```
class usuarios{
        //Registrar dato a la BD
        public static function registrar($datos){
            include("funciones.php");
            $con = conexion("root", "root");//Hago la conexion
            //Hago la consulta
            $consulta = $con->prepare("insert into usuarios(CodUsa, nombre, usuario, pass, pais, profesion, edad) values(null, :nombre, :usuario, :pass, :pais, :profesion, :edad)");
            //Ejecuto la consulta
            $consulta->execute(array(
                                ':nombre'=>$datos[0],
                                ':usuario'=>$datos[1],
                                ':pass'=>$datos[2],
                                ':pais'=>$datos[3],
                                ':profesion'=>$datos[4],
                                ':edad'=>$datos[5]
            ));
        }//end function

        //Verificar si existe
        public static function verificar($usuario){
            include("funciones.php");
            $con = conexion("root", "root");
            $consulta = $con->prepare("select * from usuarios where usuario = :usuario");
            $consulta->execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));
            $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
            return $resultado;
        }//end function
    }
```

Recuerda poner como argumento en los include() la ruta hacia tu archivo de funciones. Ejemplo include("directorio/funciones_mias.php");

Comment: Me ha servido, muchas gracias!! Pero me sigue apareciendo un error:  Error fatal: llame a una función miembro prepare () en la cadena en C: \ wamp \ www \ Red_Social \ clases \ clases.php en la línea 22

Comment: Lo de poner includes de las funciones no me sirve...

Comment: Has comprobado que en la funcino conexion no entre en el Catch? Tiene pinta de que entra en el catch y por eso te salta el error, porque $con toma el valor con el mensaje del error.

Comment: Lo acabo de comprobar y tenía un fallo de escritura y puse mal el nombre de la base de daatos, ahora me entra en el try, pero no me añade los campos a la  base de datos....

Comment: Prueba a quitar el CodUsa, y el null, es decir, prueba como si el codusa no existiese, si en bd esta como autoincrement, te lo generará igual. Un saludo.